# Finding all points where the electric potential is zero and plotting it

Tags: java, physics

```java
public class physics2 {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        double k=9*10^9;       // Constant k
        double q=6*10^(-9);   // Charge of q
        double Q= -1 * 10^(-9);    // Charge of Q
        int Pqx = 0; // X coordinate of charge q
        int Pqy = 0; // Y coordinate of charge q
        int PQx = 10; // X coordinate of charge Q
        int PQy = 0; // Y coordinate of charge Q


        for (double Px = 7.10102; Px <= 16.8989 ; Px+=0.00001) {
            for (double Py = -8.98; Py <= 8.98; Py+=0.00001) {

                double Vq = (k * q) / Math.sqrt(Math.pow((Px-Pqx),2)+Math.pow((Py-Pqy),2));  // Electric Potential of charge q

                double VQ = (k * Q) /  Math.sqrt(Math.pow((Px-PQx),2)+Math.pow((Py-PQy),2));  // Electric Potential of charge Q

                while (Vq==-VQ){
                    System.out.println("["+Px+","+Py+"]");
                }}

        }


    }
}
```

There are two charges in the coordinate system.First one is at the point(0,0) and has +6 nano-Couolomb. The other one is at the point (10,0) and has -1 nano-Coulomb charge.The subject is to find and plot all the points where the Electric Potential is zero. I write that but it runs very long time and I can't get any outputs. Where did I wrong? I can't see.

Answer (score 1):

First try replacing `while (Vq==-VQ)` with  `if (Vq==-VQ)`. I think your program gets stuck in an infinite loop there. That should fix the problem of nothing being printed.

If program is still slow, it's due to the large amount of points that you process. You should somehow reduce that number, maybe trying points close to those two points first.

And finally, here is a good explanation of how to [compare doubles](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/basics/correctly-compare-float-double/).